# Java Streams verify that there is exactly one result

Tags: java, lambda, stream

Often, using lists I am coming to a case like below (lets say a user contains an ID and an Name):

```
List<User> users = loadFromDb();
List<User> lookingForIdResultList = user.stream()
.filter( u -> u.getId() == 1234)
.collect(Collectors.toList())

if(lookingForIdResultList.size() == 0) throw UserNotFoundException()
if(lookingForIdResultList.size() > 1) throw MultipleIdsNotPermittedExcpetion()

User searchedUser = lookingForIdResultList.get(0);
System.out.println("Username is "+ searchedUser.getName())
```

Im asking, if there is a way to shorten the validation using java streams api?

**This ist just an oversimplified example, the problem is generic. I don't want to load users from db.**

Tanks!

Comment: Why don't you pass the id to the db query already and just check for the number of returned results? And why can there be multiple users with the same id anyway? You state you've used that as an example so if the problem is more generic: does it always involve loading data from the db?

Comment: This particular example reeks of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) in that `loadFromDb` should probably receive an argument to put in a `where` clause and filter the list of user beforehand.

Comment: Even if there is a way to shorten it, I'm not sure it would still be a readable solution.

Comment: You are totally right. In this particular case the there are better solutions but as @Thomas mentioned, this is just an over simplified example and the problem ist more generic. No, the data are not only from databases, sometimes from foreign apis or other internal calculations. The question is only about validating the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Guava library has Collectors `toOptional()` and `onlyElement()` for exactly this use-case:

```
// throws exception if there is not exactly 1 matching user
User searchedUser = users.stream()
    .filter(u -> u.getId() == 1234)
    .collect(MoreCollectors.onlyElement());
```

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.guava/guava/28.0-jre/com/google/common/collect/MoreCollectors.html#onlyElement--

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do validation within your code, then it won't get much shorter, but you can make the code much more readable.

A small optimization would be to use `count()` instead of `collect()`:

```java
users.stream().filter(...).count();
```

In general I'd build some helper functions, that do the job, so your code will just look cleaner and more readable:

```java
List<User> users = loadFromDb();
validateUsers(users); // throws exception
```

The `validateUsers` method can then be further abstracted, if you need similar functionality in several places:

```java
static void validateUsers(List<User> users) {
  validateListHasExactlyOne(users, user -> user.getId() == 1234);
}

static <T> void validateListHasExactlyOne(List<T> list, Predicate<T> pred) {
  long count = list.stream().filter(pred).count();
  if(count == 0) throw ...
  if(count > 1) throw ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that streams might not always be the best option here. A plain old for loop might be easier to read and write and faster as well (at least if you don't use `parallelStream()`).

```
static <T> T exactMatch(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
  T result = null;
  for(T element : list) {
    if( predicate.test(element) ) {
      if(result != null) throw new DuplicateException(); //or some other exception 
      result = element;
    }
  }
  if( result == null ) throw new NoSuchElementException();
  return result;
}
```

This looks longer but it has some advantages:

- it checks for duplicates and returns the single result using only one iteration (counting results in a stream and then getting one would require 2 iterations)
- no intermediate list required, i.e. no additional memory

There is a disadvantage though: it would be single-threaded. If parallelization is required you'd probably be better off using `parallelStream()`.

If you need to be able to also specify the exceptions you could try something like this (with the specific exceptions either being unchecked or inheriting from base exceptions):

```
static <T> T exactMatch(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate, 
                        Supplier<D extends RuntimeException> duplicateSupplier, 
                        Supplier<N extends NoSuchElementException> noElementSupplier) {

   //same as above but using "throw duplicateSupplier.get()" etc.
}
```

You could also make overloads to use standard exceptions, e.g.

```
static <T> T exactMatch(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
  return exactMatch(list, predicate, DuplicateException::new, NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```